# gradle+gretty:Could not find jai_core.jar

Tags: gradle, gretty

when I follow up http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html, I got a error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':compileClasspath'.
>
> Could not find jai_core.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3). Searched in
> the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.jar

gradle's version is 3.3,please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried the repository entry above and it didn't seem to work for me. What worked from me is the code below.

```
    repositories {
     maven {
            url = uri("https://nexus.geomatys.com/repository/geotoolkit/")
     }
     mavenCentral()
   }
```

It also seem to not work until I added the mavenCentral()  after the custom repository. Also I used kotlin build.gradle so might need to translate to gradle's dsl

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem with  jai_core-1.1.3.jar in a fx project like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
            url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
            artifactUrls  "http://maven.geotoolkit.org"
     }
}
```

as a replacement in the build.gradle for:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // enable this to use snapshot versions of Gretty:
    // maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
  }
```

Hope it helps.